Synthetic control method: Unit's weights, predictors weights, and p-values
I'm using the R package 'synth' and have 2 quick questions:

I have around 100 units in my donor pool. In some analyses, many units are assigned weights greater than 0. There are about 4-5 with large weights (e.g., 0.30 or 0.40), but many of the rest have very small weights that are greater than 0 (e.g., 0.001 or 0.003). Does that indicate a problem with my model? I saw in several papers that only few units are assigned weights greater than 0.

I use my outcome as a predictor for the pre-treatment period. In some cases, I get that its weight is greater than 0.90. I guess it makes sense, but is it normal? why then should I use outher predictors?


Thanks!

Could you please explain what it means to be "assigned" weights, what these weights represent, and how they function in your model?

Question 1
Tiny weights are not very concerning since they are small. But parsimony is a virtue, so you can induce some sparsity to make them disappear.
The identity and magnitude of non-zero coefficients give you important information to interpret the nature of the estimate and evaluate its validity and the potential for biases.
Advice 1: I would make a series of plots graphing each predictor over time for the non-zero units (both outcome and covariates). If it's a predictor that you are averaging over the entire pre-treatment period (so no time series), look where the treated unit(s) falls in that distribution. Focus on variables with high V-weights. You will often see something pop out explaining why that tiny-weighted unit was selected. For example, it may share a large idiosyncratic shock with the treated unit. This is not inherently bad if it's capturing something important that will repeat post-treatment (more on that below). Another example is when there is one tiny-weighted unit way above the treated one and another way below that both seem weird in some way. That can indicate an overfitting problem, since they may not be very good counterfactuals. I once saw a treated unit in Ohio with high weights on Alaska and Hawaii, which made no sense.
Advice 2: There are also things you can do to encourage sparseness:

Aggregate the predictors a bit more (or drop some). Sparseness is a function of how many variables you are trying to re-weight (both outcome and covariates).
Don't use the periods with the idiosyncratic shared shocks in calculating the W-weights. Exclude them from aggregation if they don't repeat post-treatment.
Trim your donor pool. More is not always better here. Typically the donor pool is much smaller than 100: 16 OECD countries for German reunification (5 picked, smallest weight is 0.09), 16 regions of Spain for terrorism (2 picked, 0.8508 and 0.1492), and 38 US states in cigarette tax paper (5 selected, smallest weight is 0.069).

More info on these things here.
Advice 3: Another robustness check would be to exclude the tiny-weight units (say, any below 0.05) from the set of potential donors and see how that changes your estimates. I would worry if they jump around, the set of high-weight countries changes, or their ranking changes. You can also consider the hit to the pre-treatment (validation) fit in terms of RMSPE from limiting the pool. There is a tradeoff between sparsity and goodness of fit here.
In the Germany reunification paper, the authors restrict how many weights are allowed to be non-zero, from 1 to 5:

Fit gets worse, country ranking stays stable, and results don't change until they get down to just 1-2 non-zero countries.
Question 2
First, where do V-weights come from? This is the most confusing thing about SCM other than the factor model stuff.
SCM uses pre-treatment outcomes and predictors (both possibly transformed) to estimate W-weights that make the potential donors look like the treated unit(s) when re-weighted. Those W-weights depend on V-weights, which indicate the relative importance of the synthetic control reproducing the values of each of the $k$ outcomes and predictors for the treated unit. So W(V).
The inferential procedure is valid for any $V$. So there are a few ways to pick V-weights on the $k$ predictors:

Set $v_k=1$ for all $k$: equal weights.
Put your thumb on the scale for your favorite(s) and specify $V$ them yourself! This has the advantage of bringing in prior knowledge from outside the study, but the disadvantage of subjectivity (and related potential for research misbehavior).
Use the inverse of the variance for each predictor.
Use an out-of-sample validation period to pick the best set. Split pre-treatment into two periods, training and validation. Use the first to search for a few candidate sets of Vs and their implied $W(V)$s. Try different optimization algorithms, ensemble them, grid search, etc. Pick $V^*$ that gives the smallest $RMPSE(W(V^*))$ in the validation period. Then use the training period to get the final $W(V^*)^*$. This works well when you a long pre-treatment period.
A data-driven procedure: use regression to obtain the variable weights contained in the V-matrix. The constrained quadratic programming routine will be used to find the best-fitting W-weights conditional on the regression-based V-weights. This works decently well and is quick. You can also iteratively search for the optimal $V$ and $W$ matrices that jointly minimize the MSPE during the pre-intervention period. I believe this is the default, but not 100% sure from reading the documentation and glancing at the code.

Back to your problem. Since you have a single weight of 0.9, that means synth used the average over the pre-treatment period rather than something more granular, which would produce more than one weight. This will always generate a V-weight close to 1 unless some pre-treatment outcome variables are dropped. You may have done that since it's not close to 1. Suppose you use the entire history of the outcome. In that case, it makes the other covariate predictors redundant, and optimizing V will put no weight on those additional predictors. If you break that mean into lags for every pre-treatment time unit, each lag will get a smaller weight, but the weights will sum to something larger compared to using an aggregation of the same time periods. This is natural since you are trying to pick $V$ so that $W(V)$ gives you a tight fit for Y. This will also be true if you omit or reduce the outcome and do this to another important predictor.
To convince yourself that predictors are still important, leave out a few periods at the end before the intervention for validation. Do four versions of synth. These are

Use full pre-intervention outcome history and the covariates.
Just the pre-intervention outcome (but not the full history, say 50% or just the even periods)
(2) plus the covariates.
covariates only

Typically, you see the best validation period fit with the third. This is not a proof, just a gut check.
